Got error when compileSdk = 35 in android/app/build.gradle
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
aapt2 E 12-03 21:27:46 15350 109664 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
aapt2 E 12-03 21:27:46 15350 109664 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar'.
error: failed to load include path /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ProcessResourcesRunnable
Android resource linking failed
aapt2 E 12-03 21:27:46 15351 109663 LoadedArsc.cpp:94] RES_TABLE_TYPE_TYPE entry offsets overlap actual entry data.
aapt2 E 12-03 21:27:46 15351 109663 ApkAssets.cpp:149] Failed to load resources table in APK '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar'.
error: failed to load include path /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-35/android.jar.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


What is the version of the Android Gradle Plugin you use? Are you on the latest one?

Please provide what you did in your project before encountering that exception. You can also show your android\build.gradle, android\app\build.gradle,  and gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties configurations.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
